# Open a file as read only mode on windows

Tags: notepad++, readonly

Is there any way to open a file as read only file on windows 7? Just like in Linux using **less** would open it by default in read only mode and **vi or vim** would open to edit it.

On windows I have looked around if there is any way using notepad++ or other popular editors to get the same behavior as on Linux. All I see is you can mark a file as read only by changing its property. But I want flexibility at user's will to open a file as read only or edit mode on windows 7.

May be like a right click and say open read only or edit mode etc. Please let me know if there is any plugin to notepad++ or any other editor which would provide these features.

I am on **Windows 7 OS**.

Comment: I am pretty sure all the editors open the file with read access and only open it with write access when you actually want to overwrite it. Do you want it to be not editable in the program? Why?

Comment: Some times you can accidentally press some buttons ex: when you are viewing a log file its good to just view it in read only mode. I felt its pretty basic feature lacking in windows which is obvious in linux

Comment: in my case, i have a web application which continuously writes to a log file. if it sees that another process has it open, log entries are sent to a new file. I'd like to avoid that by opening the file in read only mode.

Comment: The question is closed so I cannot add this answer: notepad++ has some command line options, one of them is `-ro`, for opening a file in read-only mode.

Comment: Another way is just go the file properties and set "read-only" attribute.

Comment: Once opened a file in the usual way, just right-click on its tab inside Notepad++ and from the popup menu chose **Read only**. You're done! --- Normally on the tab of a file opened in Notepad++, to the left of the file name, the **floppy disk icon** is blue for saved files and red for files with unsaved edits; to signal that a particular file is open in read-only mode, such an icon turns **gray**.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can open the file in Emacs, Alt-x and type "toggle-read-only".